# How to filter an array value if it containes some string

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions, filterfunction

I have an array that looks like this

```
[ { day: 'Friday', time: '14-16 Free' },
 { day: 'Friday', time: '16-18 Free' },
 { day: 'Friday', time: '18-20 Free' },
 { day: 'Friday', time: '20-22 Fully booked' } ]
```

and I want to filter out any value that doesn't include 'Free' in it, I tried with the length but it didn't work, can somebody explain to me why?

```js
var array = [ { day: 'Friday', time: '14-16 Free' },
     { day: 'Friday', time: '16-18 Free' },
     { day: 'Friday', time: '18-20 Free' },
     { day: 'Friday', time: '20-22 Fully booked' } ];
console.log(array.filter((e) => e.time === (e.time.length < 11)));
```

Comment: What does the length have to do with whether it contains `Free`? Use `indexOf('Free')`

Comment: Why are you comparing `e.time` with a boolean?

Comment: If you want to use the length, just return the comparison with `11`, don't compare it again with the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) instead:

```
let data = [ 
 { day: 'Friday', time: '14-16 Free' },
 { day: 'Friday', time: '16-18 Free' },
 { day: 'Friday', time: '18-20 Free' },
 { day: 'Friday', time: '20-22 Fully booked' }
];

let result = data.filter((e) => e.time.indexOf('Free') === -1);

console.log(result); // [{day: "Friday", time: "20-22 Fully booked"}]
```

The Plunker is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Kw6Kdu?p=preview).

Comment: The same nothing changed

Comment: @Jason Oh, you need the "Free" items to be filtered out, so I changed condition from `!== -1` to `=== -1` and I think it is done. I also added plunker demo to the answer.

Comment: I see I had to save it in another value to make it work, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following using `ES6`'s `includes()`:

```js
var array = [ { day: 'Friday', time: '14-16 Free' },
     { day: 'Friday', time: '16-18 Free' },
     { day: 'Friday', time: '18-20 Free' },
     { day: 'Friday', time: '20-22 Fully booked' } ];

var res = array.filter((e) => (!(e.time.includes('Free'))));
console.log(res)
```